# marionette itemview наследовать свойства темплейта

Tags: javascript, шаблоны, marionette.js

Создаю на форме текстовое окно:

```
var QueryTextView = Mn.ItemView.extend({ 
    template: $(textQueryTemplate)[0].outerHTML,
});
this.querytextView = new QueryTextView();
this.getRegion('selectFieldValue').show(this.querytextView); // отображение текстового поля
```

код темплейта:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <input type="text" class="select-field-value" value="Введите значение"/>
</script>
```

Во время работы слова "Введите значение" заменяются на нужное слово, которое мне нужно получить и обработать. Я пытаюсь сделать это так:

```
var value = this.querytextView.value;
```

Но у элемента `this.querytextView` нет свойства `value`. Судя по логу, код темплейта хранится в свойстве $el -> 0 -> innerHTML. Как можно вытащить значение `this.querytextView`?

Comment: Спасибо за тревогу! Она была крайне полезна!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного измените класс View

```js
var QueryTextView;

QueryTextView = Mn.ItemView.extend({
  
  template: $(textQueryTemplate)[0].outerHTML,
  
  ui: {
    input: '.select-field-value'
  },
  
  getValue: function() {
    return this.ui.input.val();
  },
  
  setValue: function(val) {
    this.ui.input.val(val);
    
    return this;
  }
});
```

Теперь можно без проблем читать/изменять значение.

```
console.log(this.querytextView.getValue()); // -> Введите значение

this.querytextView.setValue('bla bla bla');

console.log(this.querytextView.getValue()); // -> bla bla bla
```

PS и да, загляните сюда [marionettejs](http://marionettejs.com/docs/current/)

Answer (score -1):

Value текстбокса можно достать с помощью jQuery. В моём случае это

```
var value = $('.select-field-value').val();
```

Comment: Плохая практика. Для этого в ItemView есть свойство "ui", через которое можно получить доступ к DOM элементам конкретного ItemView. Дальше, проблему получите так же, если у вас несколько таких ItemView (списки, карточки итд). Не делайте так.

Comment: Я как раз столкнулась с этим только что. Спасибо!